# Postgresql query using recursion and selfjoin

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have an assignment and I am having trouble with one question.  Basically I have a table like to one below.  Alex is a player and the table is showing the team he has played with in every season. Note that a season start in a specific year and ends in the following year.  I need to use only SQL (no cursors) to produce the output as illustrated in the second table were the career of Alex is shown only in two rows as opposed to the first table were the career of Alex is shown in four rows.

I have hardly tried to solve this question but cannot understand how to produce the output in the second table. I can perceive that I have to use CTE since I can see the Year_End is equal to the Year_Start of the following row.  I have also tried to research on the net but since this is a very specific question I cannot find any relevant solutions.  I have also posted my query so far since I think I am on the right track but now I'm stuck.

```
**TABLE records**
Id   | Name | Team_Name    | Year_Start |  Year_End
---------------------------------------------------
100  | Alex | New Team     | 2010       |  2011
101  | Alex | New Team     | 2011       |  2012
102  | Alex | Best Eleven  | 2012       |  2013
103  | Alex | Best Eleven  | 2013       |  2014

**Required result from query**
Name  | Team Name   | Year_Start | Year_End
-------------------------------------------
Alex  | New Team    | 2010       | 2012
Alex  | Best Eleven | 2012       | 2014
```

My query so far...

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(id, name, team_name, year_start, year_end) AS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    history
    WHERE   name = 'Alex'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  history.id, history.name, history.team_name, history.year_start, history.year_end
    FROM    cte, history
    WHERE   cte.year_start = history.year_end 
)
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte;
```

Query that produced the requested result.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(id, name, team_name, year_start, year_end) AS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    history
    WHERE   name = 'Alex'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  history.id, history.name, history.team_name, history.year_start, history.year_end
    FROM    cte, history
    WHERE   cte.year_start = history.year_end 

)
    SELECT  team_name, MIN(year_start), MAX(year_end)
    FROM    cte
    GROUP BY team_name;
```

Comment: Could you do something with a `GROUP BY` for the Name and Team and a `MIN` and `MAX` for the dates, or would they have to be in sequential order.  I.E.: What would the result look like if Alex went to New Team for 2014 to 2015?

Comment: Yes, if Alex went to New Team for 2014 to 2015 the final output would have three rows. Honestly I can't figure out how I can use GROUP BY, MIN, MAX in this situation!

Comment: I solved this query. I added the answer at the end of the question. As you said if in year 2014/2015 Alex plays with New Team the query is invalid. In such case I think that cursors should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get your desired result

<kbd>[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ffb89/2)</kbd>

```
Select Distinct t.Name,t.Team_Name,b.YStart,b.YEnd 
FROM t INNER JOIN(
              Select Team_Name, Min(Year_Start) YStart,Max(Year_End) YEnd
              FROM t
              Group BY Team_Name ) b
ON t.Team_Name = b.Team_Name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select Name, Team_Name, min(Year_Start) startY, max(Year_End) endY
from t group by Name, Team_Name
```